# css inline-block doesn't work in firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I have an one column bootstrap table and each cell contains two divs with text and buttons.

in Chrome, cell content is rendered as expected in one row

[image]

but in firefox the cell content is rendered "in two rows"

[image]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8huu795c/9/)

**html**

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var data = [{"id":"973","email":"usr3@usr3.com"},{"id":"17f","email":"prom3@prom3.com"},{"id":"29e","email":"prom8@prom8.com"}];

class TableRowButtons extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this._handleDeleteClick = this._handleDeleteClick.bind(this);
        this._handleResetClick = this._handleResetClick.bind(this);
        this._handleEditClick = this._handleEditClick.bind(this);
    }

    _handleDeleteClick(e){
        console.log(e);
    }

    _handleResetClick(e){
        console.log(e);
    }

    _handleEditClick(e){
        console.log(e);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="row-container">
                <div className="row-text-container">
                    {this.props.cellContent}
                </div>
                <div className="row-buttons-container">
                    <button className="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onClick={this._handleDeleteClick}>Delete</button>
                    <button className="btn btn-warning btn-xs" onClick={this._handleResetClick}>Reset Password</button>
                    <button className="btn btn-info btn-xs" onClick={this._handleEditClick.bind}>Edit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class TestTable extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this._handleEditClick = this._handleEditClick.bind(this);
        this._handleResetClick = this._handleResetClick.bind(this);
        this._handleDeleteClick = this._handleDeleteClick.bind(this);
        this._handleRowClick = this._handleRowClick.bind(this);
    }

    _handleRowClick(row){
        console.log(row);
    }

  _handleDeleteClick(rowContent){
        console.log(rowContent);
    }

    _handleResetClick(rowContent){
        console.log(rowContent);
    }

    _handleEditClick(rowContent){
        console.log(rowContent);
    }

  render(){

    var that = this;

    function onAfterTableComplete(){

        }

        const options = {
            onRowClick: this._handleRowClick,
            afterTableComplete: onAfterTableComplete
        };

    function rowFormatter(cell, row){
            return <TableRowButtons
                    cellContent={cell}
                    rowContent={row}
                    onDeleteClick={that._handleDeleteClick}
                    onResetClick={that._handleResetClick}
                    onEditClick={that._handleEditClick}
                    />;
        }

     return (
       <BootstrapTable
                    data={data}
                    striped={true}
                    hover={true}
                    condensed={true}
                    pagination={true}
                    search={true}
                    options={options}>
                    <TableHeaderColumn
                        isKey={true}
                        dataField="email"
                        width="200"
                        dataSort={true}
                        dataFormat={rowFormatter}>Email</TableHeaderColumn>
                </BootstrapTable>
     );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TestTable />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**css**

```
.btn-danger {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  .btn-warning, .btn-info{
    margin-right: 5px;
  }

  td .btn{
    float: right;
  }

  .row-container{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  }

  .row-container div{
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .row-buttons-container{
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
  }
```

Comment: Firefox is the only browser which applies `float: right` to `inline-block` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see is the `white-space: nowrap;`
change it, maybe it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna say Firefox is correct on this one.

Let's have a look what you get when you remove the `float`. You have something like this:

> email@example.com
>   [Edit] [Reset Password] [Delete]

This is because they are `<div>` elements and as such are blocks.

Then you apply the `float:right` to the button set. My question is: why do you expect the buttons to move up? They should (and in Firefox, do) only move right.

To get the effect you want, consider having the buttons appear before the email in the HTML source. This will make them float appropriately in all browsers.

Comment: If you remove the `float` then both are on the same line, because both are set to `inline-block` .

Comment: @t.niese Consider me corrected, I missed that part! In that case, it would seem that Firefox doesn't like the combination of `inline-block` and `float`, which is arguable as to which is correct - do you apply `float` first and then `inline-block`, or vice versa?

Comment: Getting `<div>` elements to be next to each other will require either using `float` or `inline-block`. You cannot use `float` on `inline` elements, and `inline-block` elements are meant to wrap text around when floated, just like images. It's almost always a mistake using both`inline-block` and `float` on the same element, for setting it aside another element.

Comment: @Narxx So basically, undefined or implementation-specific behaviour, which is why Chrome and Firefox disagree?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I guess so. But I wouldn't rush blaming browsers for inconsistency when the user is trying out CSS codes without fully understand what they really do :)